# iOS AutoLayout stacked views flexible height

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm having trouble getting a vertical stack of views (one of them with flexible height) to behave the way I want them to using IB and AutoLayout.

I'll greatly appreciate any and all pointers on constraints and such to achieve this.

This is the setup:

[image]

A ScrollView wraps all these views, you'll see why in a moment.

And this is what I want to achieve:

**ScrollView**

- Should always span the entire window (minus the nav bar obviously)

**Top ImageView**

- Should always span the entire width of the parent
- Constant height (100)

**Label A**

- Should always span the entire width of the parent
- Constant height (25)

**Label B**

- Should have a constant "padding" to Label A, Label C, and to the parent on the sides.
- Should be vertically expandable. Its content can vary from a couple of lines to a few paragraphs (Hence the scrollview parent. The sizing is done in code when the content is known.)

**Label C**

- Same as Label A, with the addition that it should always be right after Label B (however tall it gets + the padding mentioned before)

**Bottom ImageView**

- Same dimensions as the Top ImageView
- Should always be right below Label C

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's a good description of what you want to achieve, but what's missing is what you've tried and in what way it's not working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I could write pages upon pages of the constraints that I've tried to make this happen but there is always some snag. What always ends up happening however, is that the result is completely unexpected. For example, a trailing and leading constraint of 0 to the superview for the sides of the views that need to span the entire width, somehow results in the views having strange widths that never spanning the width of the parent...

I would assume there is a 'correct' way to achieve this regardless of what I have tried, no?